# CSS 3 Keyframes Animation (Opacity) Causes Images to Blur at the End

Tags: html, css, animation

The animation happens perfectly, images not blurred etc. But when it finishes, image is blurred and stays like that. The browser I am testing is Chrome, but regardless of browser, it happens. All the images used in blink animation are not scalet, they are shown as in their original size. Here's my CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    11%, 22% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    33%, 100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes blink {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    11%, 22% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    33%, 100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes blink {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    11%, 22% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    33%, 100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}

@keyframes blink {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    11%, 22% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    33%, 100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}

.blink {
    opacity:0;

    -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 6s;
    -o-animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-duration: 6s;

    -webkit-animation-name:blink;
    -moz-animation-name:blink;
    -o-animation-name:blink;
    animation-name:blink;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.delay-1{
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    -o-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

.delay-3{
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
    -o-animation-delay: 3s;
    animation-delay: 3s;
}

.delay-5{
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 5s;
    -o-animation-delay: 5s;
    animation-delay: 5s;
}

.loop {
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.timingEaseIn {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}
```

And

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
-moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
-o-animation-fill-mode:both;
animation-fill-mode:both;
```

is coming from another .css file. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Probably has nothing to do with the code you are showing. Search your CSS for "blur" or "filter".

Comment: @Jonathan @K K Thanks! I wrote the whole css. There's no blur or filter. And the funny thing is that it does that for some images, but not for every one, so it might be hard to replicate it, even in the fiddle. But I am creating one.

Answer (score 1):

Same-thing is happening to me, 
if I add

`-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);`

it no longer blurs for me.

Comment: Sorry for a very delayed comment but I'll check and mark your answer as correct. The problem is I can no longer have this issue. Did nothing but it went away when I deployed my site on a web server.