# Keyframe animation making image blurry when it scales

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have elements with a background image. I am using a keyframe animation to grow those elements on page load. The elements are becoming blurry and then adjusting about 5 seconds after they grow. Does anyone know a fix for this? Below is my code and what I have tried:

https://jsfiddle.net/ozy4dpk0/

animation:

```
@keyframes animation {
  0% { transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  4.2% { transform: matrix3d(2.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.549, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  8.31% { transform: matrix3d(2.768, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.884, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  12.51% { transform: matrix3d(3.064, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.032, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  16.62% { transform: matrix3d(3.127, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.063, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  27.73% { transform: matrix3d(3.026, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.013, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  38.84% { transform: matrix3d(2.995, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.997, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  61.06% { transform: matrix3d(3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  83.28% { transform: matrix3d(3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  100% { transform: matrix3d(3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
}
css:

.animation-target {
  animation: animation 5000ms linear both;
}

#two-box {
  background-image: url("your-brand-here.jpg");
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #7f8c8d;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="two-box" class="first-row-styles animation-target"></div>
```

Comment: this seems like it is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27331767/css-3-keyframes-animation-opacity-causes-images-to-blur-at-the-end

Comment: The code I posted includes both of those properties @pparas

Comment: I can't figure it out either.  But... check out [this posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37173839/jquery-add-only-one-class-on-hover/37173931#37173931) and [this awesome library at Github](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css).  Not sure where you are going but that animate library is way cool, easy to use.  They use a slightly different technique for animation, but you can see all their original CSS code in raw form.

Comment: Unrelated, but you can use `5s` instead of `5000ms` for the animation duration